# Replace regex pattern

Tags: regex, string

I need to find a pattern in a Java String and replace for another string.

I have two kinds of Strings

1- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, it. Integer pos laciniA.
2. Lorem ipsum dolorelit. Curabitur pretium maL.

What I need to do is to find a "." that don't have a number before it and replace by ";"

I've found the regex to do this like str.replaceAll('\.', '\\;');

The problem with this patter is that when it find the String "2." it changes by "2;"

Another solution is str.replaceAll('[a-zAz]\.', '\\;'); but it replace the last letter before ".".

Someone can help-me with this?

Comment: Do you mean you need [`str.replaceAll("(?<!\\d)\\.", ";")`](https://regex101.com/r/xbyV8m/1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I need to do is to find a "." that don't have a number before it and replace by ";"

You may leverage a negative lookbehind:

```
String result = str.replaceAll("(?<!\\d)\\.", ";");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xbyV8m/1)

**Details**:

- `(?<!\d)` - fails the match if there is a digit before the current location
- `\.` - matches a literal `.`